# iTextSharp - How to get the current line number of a column after adding one or more paragraphs

Tags: c#, itext

I am adding paragraphs into Column Text and would like to know 
 what would be the line number.

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
   ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
   ct.SetSimpleColumn(Columns[columnNo]);
```

Suppose:

The current column has:  maxY = 748, minY = 116
I am using font size 8.5 and line height= 10.8f

From my understanding, this column can have (748-116)/10.8 = about 58 lines.

Suppose I am adding 3 paragraphs that will fit in 15 lines.
( using 'ct.AddElement(paragraph);' to add paragraphs)

I would like to be able to get the current line number after adding the 3 paragraphs or after each paragraph if possible.

Many thanks

Comment: The problem is that there may be paragraphs with different font sizes or even entirely different content pieces (e.g. images), probably with extra space before and after. Thus, the *concept* of a line as a *measure of height* in general does not make sense here.

Comment: Nonetheless, the concept of the current *y* coordinate does make sense. You might be interested in inspecting the `ct.YLine` value.

Comment: I have tried to look at ct.YLine unfortunately, it seems to return the same value whatever I add. how should it be used?

Comment: It changes after `go`.